# Why does the compiler allow this?

Tags: c++

The following compiles successfully:

```
struct XX {
  int element;
};

int main ()
{
  XX  XX, prev_XX  ;
  prev_XX = XX;
  XX = prev_XX;  //  ??? NO error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
}
```

How does compiler know whether it's a type or a variable?

**Edit :**

An error for this : (from sftrabbit's example)

```
int main ()
{
    XX XX, prev_XX;
    XX XX2; // error: expected ';' before 'XX2'
}
```

Comment: I guess it is the syntax. Why should it be a type if you have nothing before the variable name. `TYPE VAR = VAL` or `VAR = VAL`

Comment: XX declaration in main shadows the global XX. Nothing special here.

Comment: @n.m. May be nothing special, but I think its not just shadowing of global `XX`

Comment: Why? It is exactly that. Like any other shadowing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable name *hides* the struct name (§3.3.10):

> A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class (10.2).

If you need to refer to the struct name specifically, you need to use an elaborated type specifier, `struct XX` (§3.4.4):

> An elaborated-type-specifier (7.1.6.3) may be used to refer to a previously declared class-name or enum-name even though the name has been hidden by a non-type declaration (3.3.10).

So the compiler knows that `XX` refers to the variable here because that's all it *can* correspond to. It won't even consider the possibility of it referring to the struct. In fact, let's see what happens if we try to use it as a type:

```
struct XX {
    int elemnent;
};

int main ()
{
    XX XX, prev_XX;
    XX XX2; // Can we continue to use XX as a type?
}
```

We actually get an error:

```
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘XX2’
```

So instead, we have to do `struct XX XX2;`, which gives no error.

Comment: Pardon, but I don't get the behavior for your last example

Comment: I'm trying to declare another variable called `XX2` of type `XX`. However, the variable name `XX` is hiding the struct `XX`, so the compiler thinks "Wtf, why have you just written two variable names with a space between them?"

Comment: Pardon, but have a badge.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the syntax of the expression.

Just like some words can be either a noun or verb - depends on the location in the sentence

Comment: I question whether the question envelopes sufficient research.

Comment: I too thought same about location thing (lhs/rhs of expression). But compiler won't allow it for second time declaration when `XX` is used as a type

Comment: @EdHeal Yes I only added an example, even before edit _"Just like some words can be either a noun or verb - depends on the location in the sentence"_ doesn't seem to be an answer. I'd be under impression that location always play the role under such scenario, but its not just location

Answer (score 1):

The name of the object hides the name of the structure. If you want to specify the structure you should use elaborated name for example

```
XX XX;
struct XX YY;
```

It was introduced in C++ because in C structure names and variables names belong to different name spaces due to the fact that in C you must always specify keyword struct with structures. In C++ it is allowed to use structure names without keyword struct but variable names hides structure names if they coinside.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subtle issue harking back to the days of C.

When you declare `XX XX;` the second `XX` (variable) shadows the first `XX` (type). You can still access the type by using `struct XX` to name it.

```
struct XX {};

int main() {
    XX XX;

    XX other; // error: expected ‘;’ before ‘other’

    struct XX another; // OK

    another = XX; // OK

    return 0;
}
```

You can check it out [here](http://ideone.com/PT6UUp).